# Plotly with shared yaxes but "linked" xaxes

Tags: python, plotly

I have two sets of data - xA, yA and xB, yB.

I want to plot with plotly two scatterplots side by side, the first with xA vs yA, the second with xB vs yB.

The plot is meant to show the difference of a phenomenon in the past (the "A" set) and now (the "B" set).

Therefore the limits of x'es and y'es can be very different, but to visually compare the two sets it would be nice that the x axes and y axes would share the same scale, which lets to show all data from both sets.

I tried with shared y-axes, and for y axes it works correctly. However, the x axes have different limits. If I try to set the x axes limits "by hand" (even if I would prefer something automatic in plotly), at first the plot is shown correctly, but if for example I zoom on a little square on the first one, the second one is resized only on the shared y axis, while the x axis remains unzoomed and therefore the plot looses significance.

How can I "link" the axes of the two plots?

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    shared_yaxes=True,
                    horizontal_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(x=xA, y=yA, mode='markers'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(x=xB, y=yB, mode='markers'), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1200)

# I would prefer not to calculate limits by hand, but even if I do the zoom is not linked on x'es
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 60], row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 60], row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you need to use `fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')`

From [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#synchronizing-axes-in-subplots-with-matches):

> ...if the subplots are created with make_subplots, the axis needs to be
>   updated with matches parameter to update all the subplots accordingly.