# Single slider for multiple plotly subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]

fig = make_subplots(1, 2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.High)), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Low)), row=1, col=2)


fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6,
                 label="6m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1,
                 label="YTD",
                 step="year",
                 stepmode="todate"),
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1y",
                 step="year",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(step="all")
        ])
    ),
    rangeslider=dict(
        visible=True
    ),
    type="date"
)
)


import plotly.offline as pyo
pyo.plot(fig)
```

I want to create one common slider for both of the plots. Currently there are two graphs but slider is working only for one of them. Is it possible to make the current slider common for all the multiple graphs in a subplot?

Comment: Since version 4.0 plotly is offline only so you can avoid `import plotly.offline `

Comment: It's not that clear what do you want to achieve. Do you mind to elaborate/provide examples?

Comment: Currently there are two graphs being generated by the above graph but the slider is working only for one of the graphs. I want a common slider for both of the graphs.

Comment: When I plot this in jupyter the slider works on both plots.  Also, just fyi, the indentation is not correct on the `for i in range(3):` loop.  It needs indentation all the way to `steps.append(step)`.

Comment: you need to [link your xaxis](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-xaxes) when you use `make_subplots`, and then use `fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')` at the end, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61799255/11305111).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly with shared yaxes but "linked" xaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794034/plotly-with-shared-yaxes-but-linked-xaxes)

Comment: Yep...it helps..thank you

Answer (score 3):

Add line below.

```
fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')
```

Comment: did't work for me. I still have two sliders for my 2x1 plot.

Answer (score 1):

first select the subplot you don't want the slider to apper, lets think it is the row=1 and col=1 subplot

then add the line

`fig.update_xaxes(row=1, col=1, rangeslider_visible=False)`

then both of the charts will have only one slider