# Python Plotly - removing slider from plotly subplot

Tags: python, plotly, ohlc

I am creating a figure with a number of subplots using plotly.  One of the figures is an Ohlc/ candlestick that has a slider.  In case of a single plot, the slider can be removed by
`fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)`.

However, this does not seem to work when the slider is in a subplot.  Any idea how to remove the slider from the subplot ?

I have a feeling that this will involve:
`fig.update_traces(meta=<VALUE>, selector=dict(type='ohlc'))` and specify the subplot row, column in update_traces, but not quite sure how to properly choose the value for meta.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a good example, so I can turn off the slider function based on the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084592/single-slider-for-multiple-plotly-subplots). (This question is how to make the slider work for both graphs.) I changed the first graph to OHLC, and the second to volume. I don't have the source or the graphs, so does that meet your intent. the intent of the second question wasn't clear.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]

fig = make_subplots(1, 2)

fig.add_trace(go.Ohlc(x=df['Date'],
                    open=df['Open'],
                    high=df['High'],
                    low=df['Low'],
                    close=df['Close']), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Date'], y=df['Volume']), row=1, col=2)


fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6,
                 label="6m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1,
                 label="YTD",
                 step="year",
                 stepmode="todate"),
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1y",
                 step="year",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(step="all")
        ])
    ),
    rangeslider=dict(
        visible=False
    ),
    type="date"
)
)

fig.show()
```

[image]